# Why libgfortran.so.5 is not located after upgrade to the newest gcc?

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, gfortran

I'm running Centos 7 with default GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.8.5. Recently, I've installed GCC 8.2.0 in the non-standard `directory /home/apps/gcc-8.2.0-install`.

[image]

I've also updated paths in my `.bash_profile` to
`PATH=/home/apps/gcc-8.2.0-install/bin:$PATH:$HOME/bin` and
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/apps/gcc-8.2.0-install/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:`.

When I check the version of `gfortran`, it says 8.2.0, but it seems that the shared library is not updated. When typing `ldconfig -p | grep gfortran` the outcome is `libgfortran.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libgfortran.so.3`, while it should be `libgfortran.so.5`. I compiled a binary with GCC 8.2.0 , however it's missing a shared library saying that:

> error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.5: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

I guess I need to switch from default libgfortran.so.3 to libgfortran.so.5. Any ideas on how to work around this problem?

Comment: `ldconfig` just prints the contents of a system library cache, I would not expect it to care for your local installations. But `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is the way to go. Did you try to export it directly in a terminal window, not relying on `.bash_profile` and similar files?

Comment: Please do not post images of text, they are worse than useless. **Verify** that your LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set as you intend and that the library in question is in fact located there.

Comment: For me, it worked after adding
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ohpc/pub/mpi/openmpi3-gnu8/3.1.4/lib:/opt/ohpc/pub/compiler/gcc/8.3.0/lib64` in `.bash_profile` file and executing `source .bash_profile` and the same doesn't work if it was `.bashrc` file.